# JSDOM image src as base64 instead of url

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

I´m using the latest JSDOM package for Node.js and want to retrieve content from a website using the convenience api fromURL.

**What do I want to achieve?**

I want to retrieve the image src. After inspecting the DOM in my browser (chrome) the src attribute is set with a valid url (e.g. "http://some-url.com"). When using JSDOM to parse the dom the src attribute is only some base64 string of the image instead of the url.

The html code looks like this (simplified):

```
<body>
    <div>
        <picture>
            <img src="http://some-url.com">
        </picture>
    </div>
</body>
```

In my setup I´ve also set the **resources** option, as JSDOM doesn´t load any subresources by default.
Any hints what I´m currently missing?

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

JSDOM.fromURL('url-link', { resources: "usable"}).then(dom => {
   const image = dom.window.document.querySelector('img');
   if (image) {
       const src = image.src;
       console.log('src: ', src); // e.g. data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20267%20400'%3E%3C/svg%3E
   }
});
```

Comment: Documentation says this needs `canvas` support - so I’m guessing, this draws images on the canvas first, and then expoert them from there, as a Data URI. _“In my setup I´ve also set the resources option, as JSDOM doesn´t load any subresources by default.”_ - probably that’s the _cause_ of your problem then, I’m guessing? You don’t _want_ it to actually load the image resource, you just want to get its URL. So, turn that option off, and see what you get then …?

Comment: It is still the same, but thank you for the tip. Can the problem be caused by lazy-loaded images? Or does it make any difference?

Comment: Depends on what lazy-loading mechanism is actually used, I suppose.